# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Post Deploy Script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to add a post deployment script to my Elastic Beanstalk. I've read a few blog posts (read the references) that reference adding a config file to the `.elasticbeanstalk` directory. The config file is supposed to create a shell script and copy it to the directory:

`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post`

In my `.elasticbeanstalk` folder, I have the following files:

config.yml

```
    branch-defaults:
      staging:
        environment: env-name
    global:
      application_name: app-name
      default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
      default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.3.1 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)
      default_region: us-west-2
      profile: eb-cli
      sc: git
```

test.config (the config I added to test out how the post deployment script works):

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_test.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      # This is my test shell script
```

After I run `eb deploy` though, the shell script doesn't get copied to the above directory. My `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/appdeploy/post` directory is empty. The `.elasticbeanstalk` folder is correct in the `/var/app/current/` directory. I also can not see anything in the log files that references the new script or an error. I've checked `eb-tools.log`, `eb-activity.log`, `cron`, and grepped all logs for keywords around those files. Still, no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions!

References:

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=137136
- http://www.dannemanne.com/posts/post-deployment_script_on_elastic_beanstalk_restart_delayed_job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right place to drop your config file is `.ebextensions` directory in your app and not `. elasticbeanstalk`. You should then see your shell script in the /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post directory.

As noted in the forum post
"Dropping files directly into the hooks directories is risky as this is not the documented method, is different in some containers and may change in the future"

Comment: Ah, doh! Stupid mistake. Thanks!